# How to get the text of a UItextfield to update?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have a uitextfield that I am trying to update with information that I query off of the internet, however the text does not show up in the textfield until I click the textfield. How can I get the text to show up on its own using objective c?

I am putting the text in the textfield using

```
self.textfield.text = title;
```

where title is an NSString.

```
if (error == nil) {

    NSDictionary *responseBody = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options: 0 error: nil];

    NSLog(@"got response: %@", responseBody);
    NSString *title=[responseBody objectForKey:@"name"];
    self.titleOfBook.text = title;
}
```

I am not looking to use a placeholder, If there is no title stored on the website I don't want it to have any text, and if there is a title stored on the website I want the view controller to update and show that the title was found. The code correctly finds the title and assigns it to `NSString *title`, but then the textfield doesn't display the title until I click on the textfield.

Comment: show the code where you are trying to set title to textfield.

Comment: edited to include the code i used

Comment: Whether you mean 'placeholder' ? Maybe you can try this.

Comment: What is your responseBody ? If possible then display here...

Comment: trying printing value of `NSString *title`

Comment: NSString *title works perfectly the UItextfield just doesn't update with the string until I click the textfield.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
if (error == nil) {

    NSDictionary *responseBody = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options: 0 error: nil];

    NSLog(@"got response: %@", responseBody);
    NSString *title=[responseBody objectForKey:@"name"];
    self.titleOfBook.text = title;
}
else {
    self.titleOfBook.text = @"";
}
```

Or else you can hide textfield if you don't want to display or having issue of placeholder text.

```
self.titleOfBook.hidden != title.length > 0; //It'll display only length greater than zero.
```

Still, it'll not updated, then make it available on main thread. UI updates will work on Main Thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

   self.titleOfBook.text = YOUR_OPERATION;
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: using the dispatch_async worked. I think it was due to me not calling the NSURL session on the main thread.

Comment: @Daniel Yea. for that we need to update UI with "dispatch_get_main_queue"

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

    if( textField.text.length + string.length - range.length > 3) // lets say 3 chars mininum
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
text
    NSDictionary *responseBody = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options: 0 error: nil];

    NSLog(@"got response: %@", responseBody);
    NSString *title=[responseBody objectForKey:@"name"];
    self.titleOfBook.text = title;
           });
        });

    }

    return YES; 
}
```

Try this.. Using Block it will help u...